# Thymeleaf Mapping an object in a form when I use enctype="multipart/form-data" does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to upload both files and data to a jetty server. I'm using the gretty plugin to debug my application

In the form, if I leave out enctype="multipart/form-data", the object maps correctly to the fields. For example, when I submit the form I can see that the correct text in the mapped object. (I also need to change files to type File.io in my classes when I do this or else I get an error mapping)

When I add the the enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form, suddenly the mapping stops working and all the mapped text boxes are passing null

Can anybody see a problem with my application?

In my application main class, I've created both a  multipartResolver bean and a MultipartConfigElement  bean

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}

@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("9999KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("9999KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.4.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'maven'

apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'


jar {
baseName = 'killesk-language'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.4.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.2.RELEASE")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el")
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31')

testCompile("junit:junit")
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Here are my 2 classes:

```
public class Vocabulary {
private int vocabularyID;
private MultipartFile fileImage;
private List<VocabularyTextAndAudio> listVocabularyTextAndAudio= new ArrayList<VocabularyTextAndAudio>();

public int getVocabularyID() {
    return vocabularyID;
}

public void setVocabularyID(int vocabularyID) {
    this.vocabularyID = vocabularyID;
}

public MultipartFile getFileImage() {
    return fileImage;
}

public void setFileImage(MultipartFile fileImage) {
    this.fileImage = fileImage;
}

public List<VocabularyTextAndAudio> getListVocabularyTextAndAudio() {
    return listVocabularyTextAndAudio;
}

public void setListVocabularyTextAndAudio(List<VocabularyTextAndAudio> listVocabularyTextAndAudio) {
    this.listVocabularyTextAndAudio = listVocabularyTextAndAudio;
}
}


public class VocabularyTextAndAudio {

private int vocabularyID;
private int languageID;
private String vocabularyText;
private MultipartFile fileAudio;

public int getVocabularyID() {
    return vocabularyID;
}

public void setVocabularyID(int vocabularyID) {
    this.vocabularyID = vocabularyID;
}

public int getLanguageID() {
    return languageID;
}

public void setLanguageID(int languageID) {
    this.languageID = languageID;
}

public String getVocabularyText() {
    return vocabularyText;
}

public void setVocabularyText(String vocabularyText) {
    this.vocabularyText = vocabularyText;
}

public MultipartFile getFileAudio() {
    return fileAudio;
}

public void setFileAudio(MultipartFile fileAudio) {
    this.fileAudio = fileAudio;
}
}
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="myform"
  action="#"
  th:action="@{/admin/addvocabularydata.do}"
  th:object="${vocabulary}"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
    <td>File to upload:</td>
    <input type="file"
           th:field="${vocabulary.fileImage}"
           name="file"/>
</tr>
<tr th:each="language, iterStat :  ${vocabulary.getListVocabularyTextAndAudio()}">
    <td><input type="hidden"
               th:id="test"
               th:name="test"
               th:field="${vocabulary.listVocabularyTextAndAudio[__${iterStat.index}__].languageID}"/></td>

    <td th:text="${T(com.killesk.language.enums.ENUM_LANGUAGES).getLocalTextPropertyStringFromInt({language.getLanguageID()})}"></td>

    <td><input type="text"
               th:id="test"
               th:name="test"
               th:field="${vocabulary.listVocabularyTextAndAudio[__${iterStat.index}__].vocabularyText}"/></td>


    <td><input type="file"
               th:id="${'languageAudioFile_id_' + language.getLanguageID()}"
               th:name="${'languageAudioFile_name_' + language.getLanguageID()}"
               th:field="${vocabulary.listVocabularyTextAndAudio[__${iterStat.index}__].fileAudio}"
               accept=".wma"/></td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

Here is the controller that catches the request:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addvocabularydata.do", method= RequestMethod.POST )
public String addVocabularyValadate( @Valid @ModelAttribute("vocabulary") Vocabulary vocabulary,
                                     BindingResult bindingResult,
                                     Model model) {


    if(vocabulary.getFileImage().getName() != null)
    System.out.println("vocab file name " + vocabulary.getFileImage().getOriginalFilename());

    if(vocabulary.getListVocabularyTextAndAudio() != null){
        for (VocabularyTextAndAudio element : vocabulary.getListVocabularyTextAndAudio()) {
            if(element.getFileAudio() != null)
                System.out.println("VocabularyTextAndAudio file name " + element.getFileAudio().getOriginalFilename());

            if(element.getVocabularyText() == null) {
                System.out.println("VocabularyTextAndAudio text is NULL!!");
            }
        }
    }

    if(bindingResult.hasFieldErrors() == true)
        return "addvocabularydata";
    else
        return "addvocabularyfile";

}
```

When I run my application and submit [image: the following values]

I get the output:

```
vocab file name apple.png
VocabularyTextAndAudio file name apple.wma
VocabularyTextAndAudio text is NULL!!
VocabularyTextAndAudio file name manzana.wma
VocabularyTextAndAudio text is NULL!!
```

If I add a MultipartHttpServletRequest mrequest to the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addvocabularydata.do", method= RequestMethod.POST )
public String addVocabularyValadate( @Valid @ModelAttribute("vocabulary") Vocabulary vocabulary,
                                     BindingResult bindingResult,
                                     Model model,
                                     MultipartHttpServletRequest mrequest
```

I can see the parameter names being passed
[image]

But when I try and get the values, they are  NULL.

I've found them buried down in the request as content parameters. See this picture
[image]

Any idea how to get the parameter values out from there?

Comment: Have you configured a multipart resolver in your Spring configuration?

Comment: Hey man, Yeah, I've a multipartResolver and MultipartConfigElement  bean declared in my main application class. I've updated the post so you should see it at the start of the question. Thanks for the response btw

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you have commons fileuoload on the classmate?

Comment: I have it autowired on the controller class -> @Autowired
    private MultipartResolver multipartResolver       but that's as much as it's mentioned. I don't have this class imported: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;

Comment: Could you try adding http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1 this to the classpath?

Comment: Hey Man, i found where the parameter values are buried in the request. I added a new picture at the end of my question above.  Any idea how to get the values out from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched over from Gretty 9 to Tomcat 8 and I could now see the values being passed

build.gradle

```
gretty {
    servletContainer = 'tomcat8'
}
```